# IOS 6 - Custom UIButton how to give my titleLabel a margin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, drawrect

I'm drawing an inset rectangular border to my UIButton subclass inside the drawRect: method.
As you can see that shape is too close to my button titleLabel frame. How can I set the titleLabel's max width/margin to avoid this?

DrawRect: method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
[super drawRect:rect];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor bluecolor].CGColor);

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 4,4);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 56, 4);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 56, 56);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 4, 56);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 4,3);

// and now draw the Path!
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

}

[image: This is the button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `self.titleEdgeInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);` in drawRect method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code....

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = button.titleEdgeInsets;
    edgeInsets.left -= 5;
    edgeInsets.right += 5;
    button.titleEdgeInsets = edgeInsets;
```

Answer (score 0):

From xCode, this can be set using the Inset property as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]